# Json and ajax Html Table

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am just new to JSON data. I created the ajax connection which is running fine. I have approx 3000 data blocks just like below. Please help me to convert the following data block in one HTML row or help me to create a parent and child array id. so it will help me to reference the data.

Thanks in Advance

```
{
  "NS IT": {
    "NS86253": {
      "stACTts": {
        "stACTt_sln_dup_devices": 0,
        "country": "GB",
        "region": "ACT",
        "stACTt_sln_ACTlACTrms_detACTils": {
          "CRITICACTL": 0,
          "OK": 0,
          "WACTRNING": 0
        },
        "pACTrentACTccountNACTme": "NS IT InternACTtionACTl",
        "stACTt_sln_devices": 1,
        "stACTt_sln_ACTlACTrms": 0,
        "ultimACTtePACTrentACTccountNumber": "ACT-00587452"
      },
      "NS86253D30TSP021": {
        "stACTtus": "INSTACTLLED",
        "modelNACTme": "Time Series Proxy",
        "customerNACTme": "NS IT InternACTtionACTl",
        "hostNACTme": "NS86253D30TSP021",
        "locACTtionACTccountNumber": "ACT-00132677",
        "locACTtion": "NS86253",
        "ACTlACTrms": {},
        "ACTssetInsightID": "204822"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to covert you object into HTML Table.. right ?

```js
let myData = {
              name:"Amoos",
              location:"Pluto",
              other_info:{
                id: 101,
                color: "Orange",
                  color_info:{hexCode: "#FF4500"}
                }
              }
              
let myDataObj = JSON.stringify(myData)


let myTableObj = myDataObj.replace(/\"/g,"").replace(/{/g,"<table><tr><td>").replace(/:/g,"</td><td>","g").replace(/,/g,"</td></tr><tr><td>","g").replace(/}/g,"</table>")


let myDataHolder = document.getElementById("myDataHolder");

myDataHolder.innerHTML = myHtmlTableObj;
```

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDataHolder">...</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance and i really appreciate your efforts  but  i am not able to fit my data in this code . May i request you to help me to do that . Thanks in advance.